# How to pass my own parameter to function of update:model-value?

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Context: Vuejs

I have a v-list, and in each list item, I have an item group.

This is the template:

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-item v-for="(category, i) in categories" :key="i" :title="category.category">
        <template v-slot:prepend>
            <v-avatar color="grey-lighten-1">
                <v-icon color="white">{{ category.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-avatar>
        </template>

        <v-item-group multiple @update:model-value="selectedUpdated">
            <v-container>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col v-for="(item, i) in category.items" :key="i" md="3">
                        <v-item v-slot="{ isSelected, toggle }">
                            <v-card :color="isSelected ? 'primary' : ''" class="d-flex align-center" dark
                                @click="toggle">
                                <div class="text-h5 flex-grow-1 text-center">
                                    <v-img cover :src="item.icon" height="125"></v-img>
                                    {{ item.title }}
                                </div>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-item>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-item-group>

    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

This is the function of selectedUpdated:

```
function selectedUpdated(item: unknown) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

When I click items in category 1, function selectedUpdated is invoked with the indexes of the items I cliked like [2, 3].

When I click items in category 2, function selectedUpdated is invoked with the indexes of the items I cliked like [2, 3].

The problem is, how can I know which category the clicked items in? Category 1 or category 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use the click event on the v-card to call a method where you can send `category` as a parameter.  You can *also* send the given `toggle` function of the slot and still call it from your method.

```html
<v-card @click="itemClick(category, toggle)">
```

```js
itemClick(category, toggle) {
  console.log(category)
  toggle()
}
```

You can also send `item` to the method as well, if needed, just make sure to always include `toggle` and call it.